# Set Programmatic URL Dropzone Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone-rails](https://github.com/ncuesta/dropzonejs-rails) to add [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to my Rails app. I'm using CarrierWave for image uploads which is working fine without Dropzone.

I'm creating my dropzone programatically. The Dropzone seems to be working to some extent as the image gets added to the drop zone but it outputs tons of random HTML. The image doesn't get uploaded either.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

My Canvas model has an :image attribute for the uploaded images. I don't know what the URL for the dropzone form should be, so I just went with `/canvases/21`, because the page I'm currently trying it on is /canvases/21. I'm guessing the URL is causing the problem.

```
var canvasDropzone = new Dropzone("#canvas", {
  paramName: "canvas[image]",
  url: "/canvases/21"
})

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

My canvas.rb:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Answer (score 0):

url should be a link to your controller create action

```
url: "/canvases"
```

and then in your routes

```
ressources canvases, only: [:create]
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `#canvas` is the id of a div. it should be the id of the form itself not the div. thats why you are not getting the dropzone styling you want.

once you do that, then no need to use url as it will be defined in the form tag also.
perhaps show us a snippet of your form and controller to be of better help.